# Undefined Terms Within Series Solution For Heat Equation Solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I am currently working on a partial differential heat equation. I have found the infinite sum form of the solution, however, I have spotted an issue with the expansion of the sum, and I am unsure how to proceed. Allow me to elaborate:

The heat flow problem is given: $$u_t = 4u_{xx}, t>0, 0<x<π,$$ $$u_x(0,t) = u_x(π,t) = 0, t>0$$ $$u(x,0) = 2 - cos(2x) + 5cos(3x), 0\le x \le π$$

Utilizing the formula for Fourier coefficients and solving the BVP, I have attained the solution: $$u(x,t) = \frac 2π\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n}-\frac{n(1-(-1)^n)}{n^2-4}+\frac{5n(1+(-1)^n)}{n^2-9}  \right)e^{-4n^2t}sin(nx)$$

There arises an issue when expanding this series, as when $n=2$ or $n=3$, the series coefficient expression becomes undefined, as dividing by either $2^2-4$ or $3^2-9$ results in a divide by zero error. My inclination is to expand the first term of the series (as the series is defined at $n=1$) and then bypass the $n=2$ and $n=3$ terms, indexing the series from $n=4$. However, I am worried that this is bad practice, and that I may be missing some fundamental understanding about the Fourier series and infinite sums.

Please advise and share your understanding. Additionally, I am happy to show my work if required. I greatly appreciate your time and aid!

Comment: Without knowing any details, I notice that the numerators are also 0? I don't know what it means though. Good luck!

Comment: @Keshav yes, the numerators of some of the fractions in these cases will also equal zero. However, this is fine as the coefficients  can be equal to zero, but to my understanding they must be defined. 0 / 0 is still undefined. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Why is your series in terms of sines? you want an even extension to force the B.C's to hold.

Comment: @operatorerror Letting u(x,t) = X(x)T(t), X(x)T'(t) = 4X''(x)T(t), X''/X = T'/(4T) = -λ. The equation can the be separated by variables: X'' + λX = 0, T' + 4λT = 0. Solving the BVP with X(0) = X(π) = 0, the only non-zero solutions are the eigenfunctions Xn = sin(nx), λ=n^2. Solving T' + 4λT = 0, Tn = e^(-4n^2t), therefore un(x,t) = XnTn = e^(-4n^2t)*sin(nx), and u(x,t) will be the infinite linear combination of un(x,t), therefore u(x,t) is the infinite summation of cn*e^(-4n^2t)*sin(nx).

Comment: It should be $X'(0)=X'(\pi)=0$, giving cosines

Comment: You can check that $\sin(nx)$ doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions $u_{x}(0,t) = u_{x}(\pi,t) = 0$. Your solution should be $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos(n x) e^{-4 n^{2} t}$$ from which you can directly read off the coefficients $$u(x,0) = \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos(nx) = 2 - \cos(2x) + 5 \cos(3x) \implies A_{0} = 2, A_{2} = -1, A_{3} = 5$$ with the rest of the coefficients identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
sU(x,s)=4U_{xx}(x,s)+2\cos(2x)+5\cos(3x),\ \ U_x(0,s)=U_x(\pi,s)=0
$$

Solving for $x$ we have

$$
U(x,s) = \frac{2}{s}-\frac{\cos (2 x)}{s+16}+\frac{5 \cos (3 x)}{s+36}
$$

and after inversion

$$
u(x,t) = 2-e^{-16 t} \cos (2 x)+5 e^{-36 t} \cos (3 x)
$$